# Which numpy function calls is cProfile hiding from me?

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

## Solution

As it turns out, `np.sum` is a python function calling `np.add.reduce`. This latter `ufunc` call *is* reported by cProfile, I presume because this is still a python object. `np.maximum` and `np.subtract` are calls to pure C functions and cProfile thinks these are atomic expressions.

## Question

I am trying to optimize a small piece of code that takes more time that I would expect. When running `cProfile` however, it does not specify which numpy function calls consume the most time, and just lists my function `_H` as consuming almost all time. Here is the code:

```py
def _H(X, granularity, knots=None, out=None, buf=None, bias=0):
    '''This is the version that I am profiling'''
    np.subtract(knots, granularity*X[..., np.newaxis], out=buf)
    np.maximum(0, buf, out=buf)
    np.sum(buf, axis=1, out=out)
    np.subtract(1-bias, out, out=out)
    np.maximum(-bias, out, out=out)
```

I am using ufuncs to reduce the number of temporary allocations, which shaved off quite some time. A more pythonic version just for readability:

```py
def _H(X, granularity, knots=None, out=None, buf=None, bias=0):
    '''slow but more readable version'''
    return np.maximum(
         0, 1 - np.maximum(
             0, knots - granularity*X[..., np.newaxis]
         ).sum(1),
     ) - bias
```

This function is called from a for loop (because the `buf` array does not fit in memory for large stepsizes):

```py
def H(X, knots, granularity, step=1_000):
    t, d = X.shape
    _, k = knots.shape

    buf = np.empty((step, d, k))
    out = np.empty((t, k))

    for i in range(0, t, step):
        _H(X[i:i + step], granularity, knots=knots,
           out=out[i:i + step], buf=buf[:min(step, t-i)], bias=0)
    return out
```

### The profiling

Here is my profiling snippet:

```py
t = 1_000_000
d = 3
p = 2
X = np.random.uniform(size=(t, d))

cProfile.run('H(X, p, 10_000)', 'profiler')
pstats.Stats('profiler').strip_dirs().sort_stats('tottime').print_stats()
```

output:

```
         1178 function calls in 0.689 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
      100    0.371    0.004    0.680    0.007 grid.py:333(_H)
      100    0.306    0.003    0.306    0.003 {method 'reduce' of 'numpy.ufunc' objects}
        1    0.008    0.008    0.689    0.689 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.001    0.001    0.681    0.681 grid.py:308(H)
      100    0.001    0.000    0.307    0.003 fromnumeric.py:70(_wrapreduction)
      100    0.001    0.000    0.308    0.003 fromnumeric.py:2105(sum)
...
```

From what I can see, almost half (0.306 seconds) of the time is spent in numpy ufuncs, i.e. `np.subtract`, `np.maximum`, and `np.sum`. However, more than half the time (0.371 seconds) is spent on "other things" in `_H`. But what exactly? What piece of code is not further specified by `cProfile`, and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From what I can see, almost half (0.306 seconds) of the time is spent in numpy ufuncs, i.e. np.subtract, np.maximum, and np.sum

You're reading it wrong. 0.306 seconds are spent in the `ufunc.reduce` method, which is used for performing reduction operations like `numpy.sum` - `numpy.sum` delegates to `numpy.add.reduce`.

Operations like `numpy.maximum(...)`, `numpy.subtract(...)`, and `granularity*X[..., np.newaxis]` don't use `ufunc.reduce`, so they're not part of the 0.306 seconds figure.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Why does cProfile specify `reduce` as the source where 0.306 seconds is consumed, but are the `maximum`, `subtract` (and the anonymous `broadcast`) not specified? These latter functions are not mentioned at all in the profiled call stack.

Comment: @Sebastiaan: `numpy.minimum` and `numpy.subtract` are NumPy ufunc objects rather than any callable type the profiler understands, so it doesn't know how to report them.

Comment: The best it could do would probably be attributing their runtime to `ufunc.__call__`, but apparently it doesn't do that.

Comment: Interesting, I would have expected similar behavior for `minimum` as for `sum`. I will split `_H` line by line in functions to see if that clarifies things, and report back.

Comment: `numpy.maximum` isn't a reduction operation. It doesn't use `ufunc.reduce`. `numpy.max` is a reduction, but `numpy.maximum` is a binary operation. `numpy.maximum` is to `numpy.max` as `numpy.add` is to `numpy.sum`.